# Carry bit of addition in IJVM

Tags: mic-1, ijvm

The IADD instruction in IJVM adds two 1-word numbers. When I add `EEEEEEEE` to itself I get `DDDDDDDC`. What happens to the carry 1? How can I get it? Is it saved in a register?

Comment: The MIC1 that interprets IJVM only has two condition codes, N and Z. The carry out from the ALU is not stored. The microarchitecture could be modified to store the carry out, like it stores the N and Z bits.

Comment: @downeyt Would you mind if I quote your comment in my answer?

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart - You may quote my comment in your answer.

Comment: If you create a table for adding 2 two-bit numbers and showing the results, without the carry bit, you might get an idea of how to detect carry without needing a carry flag.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the carry-out bit is lost.

No version of the [IJVM Assembly Language Specification](http://www.ontko.com/mic1/jas.html) that I've come across says anything about a carry-out bit, or carry flag.

> IADD    Pop two words from stack; push their sum

[downeyt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4387162/downeyt) adds:

> The MIC1 that interprets IJVM only has two condition codes, N and Z. The carry out from the ALU is not stored. The microarchitecture could be modified to store the carry out, like it stores the N and Z bits.